# Issue on Parsing image url from image tag

Tags: android, url, imageurl, android-parser

I have written the code for parsing image url from `<image>` tag.

The code is below:

```
NodeList imageLink = docElement.getElementsByTagName("image");
            String nUrl;
            if (imageLink.toString() != null) {
                Element element = (Element) imageLink.item(0);
                NodeList imageUrl = element.getElementsByTagName("url");
                if (imageUrl.toString() != null) {
                    Element imageFirst = (Element) imageUrl.item(0);
                    nUrl = imageFirst.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<..............Image Url is : "
                                    + nUrl
                                    + ".....................>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.....");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<..............Image Url is null : .....................>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.....");
                    nUrl = "http://static.dnaindia.com/images/710/logo_dna_rss.gif";
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<..............Image tag is not found.....................>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.....");
                nUrl = "http://static.dnaindia.com/images/710/logo_dna_rss.gif";
            }
```

It was working fine with the `rss feed which having <image> tag`. I want to set default image for the Rss which does not having `<image>` url.

But my code showing `java.lang.NullPointerException` in this line `NodeList imageUrl = element.getElementsByTagName("url");`.

How to check null for `NodeList`?

And give me any idea to rectify it.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: It's the `element` object that is null. `if( null != element)` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround yor code `NodeList imageUrl = element.getElementsByTagName("url");` with try-catch and catch the exception if no `url Tag is found.

Like this

```
try{
    NodeList imageUrl = element.getElementsByTagName("url");
} catch(NullPointerException e){
    nUrl = "http://static.dnaindia.com/images/710/logo_dna_rss.gif";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps...